# Show the polynomial $[(x - a_1) \cdots (x - a_n)]^4 + 1$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are distinct integers and let

$$
f(x) = [(x - a_1) \cdots (x - a_n)]^4 + 1.
$$

Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For the case $f(x) = [(x - a_1) \cdots (x - a_n)]^2 + 1$, I supposed $f(x)$ was reducible ($f(x) = g(x)h(x)$) and got to a contradiction manipulating the degrees of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, using a result concerning the $n$ values $a_1, \dots, a_n$ for which $f(x) = 1$. However, I tried to adapt this same argument here and it didn't work because now the degree of $f$ is higher ($4n$) and the contradiction doesn't arise immediately.

How should I proceed?

Comment: a fourth power (or square) cannot be negative in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317622/11619). Not sure this is a duplicate of that, but looks like a better match than Dietrich's suggestion. May be I missed something? Wouldn't be the first time :-/

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand either... I've looked into that one and it's pretty much the same thing I did when I solved it. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: May be you can milk something out of the fact that the derivatives $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ must vanish at all the $a_i$s. See Nils' comment under Georges' answer in the linked thread. I'm not sure. I need sleep.

Comment: Anyway you might be interested in this (or anyone that takes the time to check it if it's correct and make it an answer): https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h66699. And also this (refers to a solution of more general problem) : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h198352.