# How to expand $x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I got $$P(x)=1+\prod_{i=0}^{2021} (x-i)$$ and need to use Eisensteins's Criteria to solve the irreducibility of $P(x)$ but I found a problem how to elaborate the coefficient and choosing prime $p$. Anyone can help?

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong but the leading and trailing coefficients both are equal to 1 since your product start with i=0. So Eisenstein's criterion does not apply to P(x). Maybe try P(x+n) for some n?

Comment: This does not work in general : $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+1$ is reducible !

Comment: For this particular polynomial , there might be a possibility to apply Eisenstein

Comment: As to the question of what the expansion of $x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-k)$ is... that is precisely what the [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) are defined as being.

Comment: $\prod _{n=0}^k (x-n)=\frac{\Gamma (x+1)}{\Gamma (x-k)}$

Comment: Is there perhaps a square missing? See my "answer".

Answer (score 1):

The usual exercise is to show that
$$
P(x)=1+\Pi_{i=0}^{2022} (x-i)^2
$$
is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. This has been solved here:

[$[(x-a_1)(x-a_2) \cdots (x-a_n)]^2 +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317622/x-a-1x-a-2-cdots-x-a-n2-1-is-irreducible-over-mathbb-q)